# Use shell variable into shell set

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

Here is my variable:

`time="$(date)";`

I have used positional parameter `set -- $time` 
to form JSON format

`JSON_FMT='{"time" : "%s"}\n'
 printf "$JSON_FMT" "${time}"`

Here the variable is not getting printed. Any solution to this ?!

Comment: Not sure what you mean (are there two different scripts?), [this](https://ideone.com/XK5PGx) works just fine, and I don't think the `set` would change that. On a side note, consider using `jq` to create JSON data.

Comment: @Aaron : its `sh` will run and get my output ! I try `jq` but its not supported on my device! Any other way that we can achieve?

Comment: Cannot reproduce; what you show here works fine. (The `set` command is unnecessary since you don't actually use `$1`.)

Comment: @SreedharanR `./prog.sh: line 3: uptime: command not found`, the uptime command isn't available on ideone's bash. It will lead to printing `{"time" :"" }` on standard output, but you should also see the above error on the standard error

Comment: What does `I have used positional parameter set -- $time to form JSON format` mean in the context of your 2 commands? Please show a minimal **complete** script that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @Aaron where does OP mention either `uptime` or `ideone`??

Comment: @arco444 in a now deleted comment where he asked me to try with `time="$(uptime)"`